# Numeric field in SP displaying 10 as 10.000000 how do i remove that?

Tags: lookup-column

I have a list look up column which fetches values from another list which is number(int), but on loading it takes it as a flaoting number.
for example the value in list firld in 10 but it is taken as 10.000000 in another list field 
i can't make it String as they will go entering characters.
How do i reslve that?

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to recreate this problem and can't.

What I'm doing:

1. Create 2 lists
2. In list 1 create a column defined as a number, with the number of decimals set to 0
3. In list 2 create a lookup refering to the ID in list one, and add a linked lookup column of the number from list 1

When you say you set it as a number(int) are you using anything other than the OOB list designer? I have done the above using the OOB list builder within the site, not Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a calculated field in the same list as the lookup list.  the calculated field used =TEXT([*your number field*],"0") and set the output type as text (in SP10 - just setting the output as text did not seem to work.)  then, instead of grabbing my number field (by which i sort and filter as numbers,) I grabbed the text field into my new list.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
I have modified your formula to format for currency. Here is the amendment:
=TEXT([your number field],"$0.00;($0.00)")